# Raspicam Camera.retrieve() error

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I write simple application and have problem with raspicam library. I've opened simpletest_raspicamm.cpp:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <raspicam/raspicam.h>
using namespace std;

int main ( int argc,char **argv ) {
    raspicam::RaspiCam Camera; //Cmaera object
    //Open camera 
    cout<<"Opening Camera..."<<endl;
    if ( !Camera.open()) {cerr<<"Error opening camera"<<endl;return -1;}
    //wait a while until camera stabilizes
    cout<<"Sleeping for 3 secs"<<endl;
   //capture
    Camera.grab();
   //allocate memory
    unsigned char *data=new unsigned char[  Camera.getImageTypeSize (        raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_RGB )];
   //extract the image in rgb format
   Camera.retrieve ( data,raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_RGB );//get camera image
   //save
   std::ofstream outFile ( "raspicam_image.ppm",std::ios::binary );
   outFile<<"P6\n"<<Camera.getWidth() <<" "<<Camera.getHeight() <<" 255\n";
   outFile.write ( ( char* ) data, Camera.getImageTypeSize ( raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_RGB ) );
   cout<<"Image saved at raspicam_image.ppm"<<endl;
   //free resrources    
   delete data;
   return 0;
```

}

And console returns me cout: 
/home/pi/Desktop/raspicam-0.0.7/src/private/private_impl.cpp:171 :Private_Impl::retrieve type is not RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE as it should be
Image saved at raspicam_image.ppm

I use raspicam 0.0.7 i tried to use every other version and nothings changes. I compile use command:

```
g++ -ggdb -o `basename server.cpp .cpp` server1.cpp -I/usr/local/include/ -     lraspicam -L/opt/vc/lib
```

I've tried to use Camera.setFormat(raspicam::RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE) and have no idea how to fix it. I work on raspberry pi 2, but on rpi3 everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the interface of `retrieve()` has been changed since v0.0.5 [according to the comments in the header file.](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/src/raspicam.h#L79)
Basically the parameter is useless now, and can be always set to `RASPICAM_FORMAT_IGNORE`, or just left blank for the C++ default parameter to kick in. The warning you're seeing basically does nothing and won't have any impact on the performance.

Format can now be set by an [independent function](https://github.com/cedricve/raspicam/blob/master/src/raspicam.h#L104)

```cpp
void setFormat ( RASPICAM_FORMAT fmt );
```

Comment: Oh.. Thank you for answering the question, but since it was 4 years ago and I have no possibility to test the solution. Somehow we have fixed it and finished our project. Cheers!

Comment: @ElBlokko  I stumped across this ticket because I had the same problem too! Thought it would be nice to leave a answer after I finally solved it, so others won't have problems. And yes it appears the issue is still there after 4 years haha.